# BeautifulSoup difference between findAll and findChildren

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

What is the difference? Don't they do the same thing - find the inside tags with given properties?

Comment: children snag what a tag contains and returns a generator - find_all finds all instances of a given tag and returns a list.

Comment: @n1c9 Looks like it's wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*findChildren*  returns a *resultSet* just as *find_all* does, there is no  difference in using either method as [*findChildren*](https://github.com/JinnLynn/beautifulsoup/blob/master/bs4/element.py#L1178) is actually *find_all*, if you look at the link to the source you can see:

```
 findChildren = find_all  # BS2
```

It's there for backwards compatibility as is `findAll = find_all # BS3`

Comment: Then why make the very same function with different name? Am I correct to assume in reality we have three(!) the same functions which do and return exactly the same thing (ResultSet - list of tags found) with the same legth and elements - `findAll`, `findChildren` and `find_all`?

Comment: @parsecer, *backwards compatibility*, if I had bs2 code I would have only had `findChildren` , if I had bs3 code I would have only had `findAll`.

Comment: So when there was bs2 there was only `findChildren` (and no `findAll` or `find_all`), then the next bs version came around and there was `findAll=findChildren` (no `find_all`, `findChildren` was left untouched), and now we have bs4 where `find_all=findAll=findChildren` (`findAll` and `findChildren` left untouched for compatibility). Is that right?

Comment: @parsecer, exactly.

Comment: Thank you very much! So it's recommended to use `find_all` since in future verisons the backward compatibility may be decreased?

Comment: @parsecer, yes, I imagine someday findAll and findChildren will be removed, always better to stick with the latest methods.