# Extracting image source using beautiful soup

Tags: django, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

From below url I need to extract image source of img tag inside div having class "owner".

[foodily.com](http://www.foodily.com/r/JvA1bioOB-cinnamon-brioche-french-toast-by-have-cake-will-travel)

having structure as below:

```
    <div class="owner">
        <a href="/u/celinesteen">
           <img src="http://img07.foodily.net/img/50x50/6c4b366907eb.jpg"></a>
        <div class="data">
           <div class="name">By
             <a data-ftrack="{&quot;a&quot;:&quot;SU&quot;,&quot;b&quot;:&quot;SULT&quot;,&quot;c&quot;:&quot;Have Cake Will Travel&quot;}" class="_track" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="/u/celinesteen">Have Cake Will Travel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
 soup.find('div', {"class": "owner"}).findChildren('img')
```

and it returns me whole image tag instead I just need source inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once, you've located the `img` element, you can use the [*dictionary-like* access to its attributes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

```
soup.find('div', {"class": "owner"}).img['src']
```

You can also get to the `img` element in one go with a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select_one('.owner img')['src']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will accept your answer in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The `findChildren` returns an array of tags. Try to get the `src` attribute from those:

```
images = s.find('div', {"class": "owner"}).findChildren('img')
for img in images:
        img.get('src')
```

prints:

```
'http://img07.foodily.net/img/50x50/6c4b366907eb.jpg'
```

Check the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) for more info.

Comment: Thank you.  Yours and alecxe answer both are right.

Comment: `findChildren` is going back to bs2 days, use find_all http://stackoverflow.com/a/38839074/2141635